# Excel - Calculate average of first 5 instances

Tags: excel, average

I am trying to calculate the average team times from a race in Excel. I have 4 columns of data to work with: individual place, individual name, Team name, and time. I believe I really only need the team name and time for this problem. So far I have been able to calculate the overall average time for each team, which consists of up to 7 runners, using the `AVERAGEIFS` function. However, I need to calculate the average time of the first 5 runners of each team ONLY and ignore the potential last 2.

I have 52 teams and 380 runners in the race. Not all teams have 7 runners. Some may have only 5 or 6. Some runners in the race do not have a full team and are not calculated in the team results.

Comment: Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: Or the input data?

Comment: Calculate rank for each player within team https://exceljet.net/formula/rank-if-formula, then calculate avarageif using rank. This is even more flexible that you need (you can calculate avarage of last 4 for example)

Comment: I ended up creating a second table using VLOOKUP to find the first 5 matching values for each team and then averaged those 5 times in a separate function. A bit messier, but only took 5 minutes for each race using that method. I used the following YouTube video as a reference to get the job done:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PC5ydyQJeo